# How to make the belongs_to model's id unnested in JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I get the following response by `render json: Oj.dump(ReportTypeSymbol.all.to_a)`

#### Current JSON format

```
report_type: "com_disagg",
symbol_code_id: {
$oid: "54bf7ff1506f6336e3020000"
}
```

#### Expected JSON format (do not nested the `symbol_code_id`)

```
report_type: "com_disagg",
symbol_code_id: "54bf7ff1506f6336e3020000"
```

#### Model definition

```
    class ReportTypeSymbol
      include Mongoid::Document
      belongs_to :symbol_code
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override `as_json` method in your model.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. It works nested relations too.
Basically it's monkey-patching the Mongoid Documents and BSON objects.

Create a file Mongoid.rb in initializers (Rails)

```
module Mongoid
  module Document
    def as_json(options={})
      attrs = super(options)
      attrs['id'] = attrs.delete('_id').to_s
      attrs
    end
  end
end

module BSON
  class ObjectId
    alias :to_json :to_s
    alias :as_json :to_s
  end
end
```